# ApiPlatform best way to convert to exist entity on mutation graphql

Tags: symfony, graphql, api-platform.com

I have this entitys for user

```
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'email is exists')]
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'user')]
#[ApiPlatform\ApiResource(
    operations: [],
    graphQlOperations: [
        new ApiPlatform\GraphQl\Query(),
        new ApiPlatform\GraphQl\Mutation(
            name: 'create',
            denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['request:create', 'shopping:create']],
        ),
    ]
)]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Serializer\Expose]
    protected $id;

    #[Assert\Email(message: 'email not valid')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', unique: true, length: 150, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['request:create', 'shopping:create'])]
    protected $email;
}
```

and this for Shopping

```
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiPlatform\ApiResource(
    operations: [],
    graphQlOperations: [
        new ApiPlatform\GraphQl\Query(),
        new ApiPlatform\GraphQl\Mutation(
            name: 'create',
            denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['shopping:create']],
        ),
    ]
)]
class Shopping
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'shoppings')]
    #[Groups(['shopping:create'])]
    #[Assert\Valid()]
    private User $user;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['shopping:create'])]
    private string $name;
}
```

And execute graphql query like this

```
mutation {
  createShopping(
    input: {
      user: {
        email: "test@foo.bar"
      }, 
      name: "foo"
    }
  ) {
    shopping {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I get error "email is exists"

I try write custom reslover to conver User entity, to exist entity like this

```
final class UserResolver implements MutationResolverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    ) {
    }

    public function __invoke($item, array $context): object
    {
        if ($item->getEmail()) {
            $existUser = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $item->getEmail()]);
            if ($existUser) {
                return $existUser;
            }
        }



        return $item;
    }
}
```

and custom resolver for Shopping because resolvers not call cascade

```
final class ShoppingResolver implements MutationResolverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly UserResolver $userResolver,
    ) {
    }

    public function __invoke($item, array $context): ?object
    {
        $item->setUser($this->userResolver->__invoke($item->getUser(), $context));

        return $item;
    }
}
```

It work if I remove #[Assert\Valid()] from Shopping entity because validation run before resolvers.

That the best way to solve this problem? Custom denormalizer or use Event system or somthing else?

Answer (score 0):

I settled on this decision. Custom denormalizer for symfony 6.3 like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Serializer\Denormalizer;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class UserDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        private readonly ObjectNormalizer $normalizer
    ) {
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $type === User::class;
    }

    public function denormalize($data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = []): mixed
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->normalizer->denormalize($data, $type, $format, $context);

        $existUser = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $user->getEmail()]);
        if ($existUser) {
            return $existUser;
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function getSupportedTypes(?string $format): array
    {
        return [
            'object' => null,
            '*' => null,
            User::class => null,
        ];
    }
}
```